# Availability Set not in Dropdown

Tags: linux, azure, high-availability

I'm trying to set up to machines in the same availability set in Azure so that I can make sure that my MongoDB database is always available.

I created an availability set for the first machine.
When I go to select an availability set for the second machine, it's not in the dropdown. It still lets me create a new one, but the existing availability set is not there.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using OpenLogic 7 for both machines, standard instance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both machines need to be in the same cloud service.
I changed that and it works.